# Why do I get "permission denied" when trying to start Python Scapy loopback interface?

Tags: python, sockets, scapy

I'm new in network(
I'm trying start loop back interface for ICMP and what I got:

```
 Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from scapy.all import *
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
>>> conf.L3socket
<L3dnetSocket: read/write packets at layer 3 using libdnet and libpcap>
>>> conf.L3socket=L3RawSocket
>>> sr1(IP(dst="127.0.0.1")/ICMP())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 334, in sr1
    s=conf.L3socket(filter=filter, nofilter=nofilter, iface=iface)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\scapy\supersocket.py", line 63, in __init_
_
    self.outs = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RA
W)
  File "c:\Python25\lib\socket.py", line 159, in __init__
    _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
socket.error: (10013, 'Permission denied')
```

What I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start scapy as root to be able to send messages with raw sockets.

Since you are running Windows, you need to figure out how to start scapy as the administrator.

Comment: I use scapy with python. Scapy should run at the administrator when python script run? or what?

Comment: I don't know how you start scapy, but if it's something you click you can probably right-click and select "run as administrator".